# Hibernate doesn't create foreign key constraints for @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-one

I have Hibernate-mapped classes, where ManyToOne annotations sometimes result in a foreign key constraint in the database (I've tried both Oracle and H2), sometimes don't.

For instance, no constraint is generated for source_id here:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "onto_entry" )
@Inheritance ( strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
@DiscriminatorColumn ( name = "term_category" )
@DiscriminatorValue ( "generic" )
@SequenceGenerator( name = "hibernate_seq", sequenceName = "onto_entry_seq" )
public class OntologyEntry extends Identifiable
{
  ...
  @ManyToOne ( targetEntity = ReferenceSource.class, cascade = {   
    CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH } )
  @JoinColumn( name = "source_id" )
  public ReferenceSource getSource ()
  ...
}
```

While I get a FK constraint generated for protocol_id here:

```
@Entity
@Table ( name = "protocol_application" )
public class ProtocolApplication extends Identifiable
{
  @ManyToOne ( cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, targetEntity = Protocol.class )
  @JoinColumn ( name = "protocol_id" )
  public Protocol getProtocol ()
  ...
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Which elements can influence such behaviour?

Comment: how did you define the other side of the relationship (for both cases) ?

Comment: Ben, there is no other side, I don't care about going from the parent to the children in this case, cause it is rarely needed and can be done via SQL/HQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer myself.

[Hibernate doesn't create join table indexes in Oracle, unless in create mode](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4263). So I've decided to do it myself, partially automating it by looking at JPA annotations. [This](https://github.com/EBIBioSamples/core_model/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/ac/ebi/fg/persistence/hibernate/schema_enhancer/DbSchemaEnhancer.java) is what I've done so far.

Answer (score 3):

Probably hibernate.dialect is set to MyISAM instead of InnoDB

MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys.

So set

```
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

or for Spring Boot

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: Please read my self-answer. It was Oracle and, apparently, for Oracle and other DBMSs constraints and indexes are created only in create mode, not while updating a schema. Fortunately, I don't use Hibernate so much these days.