# Java servlet hibernate, can not join column on project run, even the set foreign key contraints is fired

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

i'm having a small problem while using java Servlet Hibernate to generate DB + tables + relationships when starting the project, the sql statement that hibernate generate is fine as i can see, i can see the new DB has been created, and also new tables too, but sadly not the relationships:

Here is the sql statement from hibernate:

Hibernate:

```
    drop table if exists account
May 06, 2023 5:50:30 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@431299a2] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists accountRole
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists category
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists invoice
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists invoice_detail
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists product
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists role
Hibernate: 
    
    create table account (
       id integer not null auto_increment,
        birthday date not null,
        full_name varchar(250) not null,
        gender varchar(20) not null,
        password varchar(250) not null,
        username varchar(250) not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=MyISAM
May 06, 2023 5:50:30 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@b614e1b] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: 
    
    create table accountRole (
       id integer not null auto_increment,
        account_id integer not null,
        role_id integer not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: 
    
    create table category (
       id integer not null auto_increment,
        name varchar(250) not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: 
    
    create table invoice (
       id integer not null auto_increment,
        created date not null,
        name varchar(250) not null,
        payment varchar(250) not null,
        status varchar(250) not null,
        account_id integer not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: 
    
    create table invoice_detail (
       id integer not null auto_increment,
        price double precision not null,
        quantity integer not null,
        invoice_id integer not null,
        product_id integer not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: 
    
    create table product (
       id integer not null auto_increment,
        created date not null,
        description varchar(250) not null,
        name varchar(250) not null,
        price double precision not null,
        quantity integer not null,
        status bit not null,
        category_id integer not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: 
    
    create table role (
       id integer not null auto_increment,
        name varchar(250) not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table accountRole 
       add constraint FKfcklc8o9ie1hkk7s8572wysjq 
       foreign key (account_id) 
       references account (id)
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table accountRole 
       add constraint FKlwdxmf96o4h5iurtam42t7xcn 
       foreign key (role_id) 
       references role (id)
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table invoice 
       add constraint FKoevv8h8t2qgym9s0cn7oh069b 
       foreign key (account_id) 
       references account (id)
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table invoice_detail 
       add constraint FKit1rbx4thcr6gx6bm3gxub3y4 
       foreign key (invoice_id) 
       references invoice (id)
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table invoice_detail 
       add constraint FKbe6c21nke5fy4m3vw00f23qsf 
       foreign key (product_id) 
       references product (id)
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table product 
       add constraint FK1mtsbur82frn64de7balymq9s 
       foreign key (category_id) 
       references category (id)
May 06, 2023 5:50:31 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@2233c799'
May 06, 2023 5:50:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

As you can see, hibernate has successfully create foreign key constraints, but when i check PhpMyAdmin, i don't see any relationship:

[image]

Here is my entities code:

Account:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "account")
    public class Account implements java.io.Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 11)
        private Integer id;
    
        @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 250)
        private String username;
    
        @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 250)
        private String password;
    
        @Column(name = "full_name", nullable = false, length = 250)
        private String fullName;
    
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name = "birthday", nullable = false, length = 10)
        private Date birthday;
    
        @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false, length = 20)
        private String gender;
    
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "account")
        private Set<AccountRole> accountRoles = new HashSet<AccountRole>(0);
    
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "account")
        private Set<Invoice> invoices = new HashSet<Invoice>(0);
    
        public Account() {
        }
    
        public Account(String username, String password, String fullName, Date birthday, String gender) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.birthday = birthday;
            this.gender = gender;
        }
    
        public Account(Integer id, String username, String password, String fullName, Date birthday, String gender,
                Set<AccountRole> accountRoles, Set<Invoice> invoices) {
            this.id = id;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.birthday = birthday;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.accountRoles = accountRoles;
            this.invoices = invoices;
        }
    
        public Integer getId() {
            return this.id;
        }
    
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getUsername() {
            return this.username;
        }
    
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
    
        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;
        }
    
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    
        public String getFullName() {
            return this.fullName;
        }
    
        public void setFullName(String fullName) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
        }
    
        public Date getBirthday() {
            return this.birthday;
        }
    
        public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
            this.birthday = birthday;
        }
    
        public String getGender() {
            return this.gender;
        }
    
        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }
    
        public Set<AccountRole> getAccountRoles() {
            return accountRoles;
        }
    
        public void setAccountRoles(Set<AccountRole> accountRoles) {
            this.accountRoles = accountRoles;
        }
    
        public Set<Invoice> getInvoices() {
            return this.invoices;
        }
    
        public void setInvoices(Set<Invoice> invoices) {
            this.invoices = invoices;
        }
    
    }
```

AccountRole:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accountRole")
public class AccountRole implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 11)
    public Integer id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
    public Account account;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    public Role role;

    public AccountRole(Integer id, Account account, Role role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.account = account;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AccountRole [id=" + id + ", account=" + account + ", role=" + role + "]";
    }

}
```

Category:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 11)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Category(String name, Set<Product> products) {
        this.name = name;
        this.products = products;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

}
```

Invoice:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
public class Invoice implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 11)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
    private Account account;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "payment", nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String payment;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String status;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Date created;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "invoice")
    private Set<InvoiceDetail> invoiceDetails = new HashSet<InvoiceDetail>(0);

    public Invoice() {
    }

    public Invoice(Account account, String name, String payment, String status, Date created) {
        this.account = account;
        this.name = name;
        this.payment = payment;
        this.status = status;
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Invoice(Account account, String name, String payment, String status, Date created,
            Set<InvoiceDetail> invoiceDetails) {
        this.account = account;
        this.name = name;
        this.payment = payment;
        this.status = status;
        this.created = created;
        this.invoiceDetails = invoiceDetails;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return this.account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPayment() {
        return this.payment;
    }

    public void setPayment(String payment) {
        this.payment = payment;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return this.created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Set<InvoiceDetail> getInvoiceDetails() {
        return this.invoiceDetails;
    }

    public void setInvoiceDetails(Set<InvoiceDetail> invoiceDetails) {
        this.invoiceDetails = invoiceDetails;
    }

}
```

InvoiceDetail:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice_detail")
public class InvoiceDetail implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 11)
    private Integer id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id", nullable = false)
    private Invoice invoice;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    private Product product;
    
    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    private double price;
    
    @Column(name = "quantity", nullable = false)
    private int quantity;

    public InvoiceDetail() {
    }

    public InvoiceDetail(Integer id, Invoice invoice, Product product, double price, int quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.invoice = invoice;
        this.product = product;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Invoice getInvoice() {
        return this.invoice;
    }

    public void setInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
        this.invoice = invoice;
    }


    public Product getProduct() {
        return this.product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }


    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


    public int getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 11)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    private double price;

    @Column(name = "quantity", nullable = false)
    private int quantity;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private boolean status;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Date created;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<InvoiceDetail> invoiceDetails = new HashSet<InvoiceDetail>(0);

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(Category category, String name, double price, int quantity, boolean status, Date created,
            String description) {
        this.category = category;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.status = status;
        this.created = created;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Product(Category category, String name, double price, int quantity, boolean status, Date created,
            String description, Set<InvoiceDetail> invoiceDetails) {
        this.category = category;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.status = status;
        this.created = created;
        this.description = description;
        this.invoiceDetails = invoiceDetails;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return this.category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return this.created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Set<InvoiceDetail> getInvoiceDetails() {
        return this.invoiceDetails;
    }

    public void setInvoiceDetails(Set<InvoiceDetail> invoiceDetails) {
        this.invoiceDetails = invoiceDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        return "Product [id=" + id + ", category=" + category + ", name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", quantity="
                + quantity + ", status=" + status + ", created=" + simpleDateFormat.format(created) + ", description="
                + description + "]";
    }

}
```

Role:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 11)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "role")
    private Set<AccountRole> accountRoles = new HashSet<AccountRole>(0);

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Role(Integer id, String name, Set<AccountRole> accountRoles) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.accountRoles = accountRoles;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<AccountRole> getAccountRoles() {
        return accountRoles;
    }

    public void setAccountRoles(Set<AccountRole> accountRoles) {
        this.accountRoles = accountRoles;
    }

}
```

My hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.test.entities.Account" />
        <mapping class="com.test.entities.Invoice" />
        <mapping class="com.test.entities.InvoiceDetail" />
        <mapping class="com.test.entities.Product" />
        <mapping class="com.test.entities.Role" />
        <mapping class="com.test.entities.Category" />
        <mapping class="com.test.entities.AccountRole" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: you can use : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830815/hibernate-doesnt-create-foreign-key-constraints-for-manytoone

Comment: @DaniyalVaghar thank you sir, that's because i have to use a different Dialect, i change it and now it work